# How to Combine Apache Derby without installing with Jar Directly

Tags: java, derby

I have application which was developed using Java and Apache Derby. I want to create executable JAR and run on any system which doesn't have derby DB.When I click on Jar file the derby also install on the system. Is it possible.

Answer (score 1):

Derby is an embeddable database. You can start and stop it within your program, as described [here](http://db.apache.org/derby/papers/DerbyTut/embedded_intro.html). You can pack the neccessary Jar into your executable Jar, so there is no need to install anything.

Answer (score 1):

In your distribution of the executable JAR, you could include the derby.jar and load it into the classpath. In the Manifest file of your executable jar you can link to it. For example your software distribution could be like this:

```
Root Folder
+ your_runnable.jar
+ db(a folder)
   +derby.jar
```

Your Manfiest file entry has:

```
 Class-Path: db/derby.jar
```